# Setting tinyMCE text data using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, tinymce, shadow-dom

I am trying to set the innerText of the *p* tag located inside the tinyMCE *body* here using javaScript but cannot seem to reach the element.

[Elements Tab of the Developer Tools.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pioxX.png)

It looks to me like there is a shadow DOM in the iframe. As when I am running the following in the console I get *null* as a result.

```
document.querySelector("#tinymce");
null
```

However if I switch in the console from "top" to "mce_6_ifr" I can now reach the wanted data:

[Console Tab of the Developer Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhgr3.png)

I am unsure how to move forward regarding this.
Any help is much appreciated !

Comment: The tinymce inside the iframe right so can you try this
`var iframe = document.getElementById('mce_6_ifr');
  var element = iframe.contentWindow.document.querySelector("#tinymce");`

Comment: HI @mariappank I tried running this "var iframe = document.getElementById('mce_6_ifr');" and it returns undefined but document.getElementById('mce_6_ifr'); returns the iframe. Any ideas here ?

Comment: I  think it wil work `document.getElementById("mce_6_ifr").contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerText `

Comment: TinyMCE has an API to load content into the editor: `setContent()`.  Have you considered using that as opposed to traversing the DOM?

Comment: @MichaelFromin I was not aware I will check this as an alternate solution here thanks for the input !

Comment: @mariappank do you want to submit your solution as an answer here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will work

```
document.getElementById("mce_6_ifr").contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerText
```

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE has APIs that allow you to load content into the editor so that you do not have to do manual traversal of the DOM.

Here is a fully working example:  http://fiddle.tinymce.com/qigaab

The key code is inside the TinyMCE init:

```
setup: function (editor) {
  editor.on('init', function (e) {
    editor.setContent('<p>This is content set via the init function</p>');
  });
}
```

This code uses the `setContent()` API to load your HTML into the editor.

Manual DOM traversal will work but relies on the HTML that TinyMCE injects ... if that changes in some fashion your DOM-based code can break.  Using the APIs ensures that you won't get breakage over time.

Comment: Thanks Michael ! This is a great solution and does seem more reliable on the long term. I have new requirements that have appeared here and now I need to display the HTML without reloading the page so using the API would not be an option due to that unfortunately. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

@Harold I can’t imagine why that would not work. Perhaps you can make a TinyMCE Fiddle that shows running code?

Comment: unfortunately I cannot share more code as this is limited to my work environment. Would the use of the API not require a reload of the page to show the data pushed in the API ?

Comment: You can call TinyMCE's APIs at any point after the editor is loaded on the page so no it would not require a page reload.  If you can't share code (or a simple example that works in the same fashion) there is not much more someone can tell you on how you could use the APIs appropriately.